# Community audiences

Tags: community

I am working on understanding page load time issues I am having in my Community.  I have a couple of test home pages that load based on the test Community user I am working with.  I have found that a home page that does not have several custom components at all loads in about 3 seconds.  I have also found that a home page that has several custom components that are hidden (via audiences) from the user takes more than double the time to load than the home page without the custom components.  This is puzzling to me because the custom components are hidden via the audience.  This seems to say that using Salesforce audiences to hide/display components causes a significant decrease in load time.  Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for issues related to loading/performance. In order to better understand why this could be, I would suggest you to consult with technical resources in order for them to measure and determine the root cause.

This is a tedious process, and when we take lwc into considerations, it can become more complex to evaluate the reason behind performance issues since there are certain development patterns that should be avoided (which are not necessary when doing standard web development)